# "contains" keyword with bracketed if-statement

Tags: autohotkey

```
if clip contains Cho,oos,ose,wor,ord
          ...
```

How do I convert the above legacy style to non-legacy style:

```
if(...)
{
      ...
}
```

For example:

```
clip = %clipboard%
```

can be converted to non-legacy

```
clip := clipboard
```

I tried

```
if (clip contains "Cho","oos","ose","wor","ord")
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm curious, why do you need/want to do this? (thinking maybe I can learn something from this)

Comment: Just to be congruent with the rest of the code because all values are taken as literals in legacy style unless we add %...% around them to indicate it is a variable.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, it's important to have a code you like and that is consistent in form. But I guess there is no practical advantages with one or the other, then. I think I found a solution, see answer.

Comment: From the [AHK documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfIn.htm), _**Caution**: The operators "between", "is", "in", and "contains" are not supported in expressions._.  You can't put them in ().

Comment: @Yane  Great catch!  But how is `clip contains Cho,oos,ose,wor,ord` not an expression by definition? Doesn't it evaluate to true or false?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine:

```
var := "schwurtzen"
if var contains % "wurt"
    MsgBox true
else
    MsgBox false
```

Comment: Evaluates true. If qoutation marks is excluded in the `if` it evaluates false.

Comment: Does this work if you add brackets for the if-condition?  Like so: if (var contains % "wurt")

Comment: No, the brackets doesn't contain an expression, so that won't work. And I can't figure out if it's possible to have several strings to match within this form, unless the MatchList is a variable var2: `if var contains % var2`. So I realise I didn't solve your problem after all.